# App Rejected for Audio Streaming over 5MB/5 Minutes? Reachability and tracking data usage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, reachability

My app was rejected because one of the features is streaming Podcast audio from a website. Apparently, it may stream over 5MB/5 minutes which is against section 9.3 of the App Store Review Guidelines (https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html).

Their suggestion would be to use Reachability to restrict that feature to WiFi. My question is, is there any other way to get around this? Perhaps to only let the user stream 5Mb worth of audio before displaying an alert to switch to WiFi? I don't see anything in Reachability about data usage... is there any other Framework that could keep track of data usage?

Comment: Just curious, is this with audio only?  I'm wondering how Netflix got around this.

Comment: Yep, I have video streaming in my app as well. No complaints there. Strange...

Comment: If that's the case, I think the argument of the guideline being reasonable due to the prevention of running up bills, etc. doesn't really hold water....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Apple's guideline is a reasonable one. It's not only to prevent users running up big data bills, but also to help reduce congestion on data networks.

As for your idea of letting user stream over cellular for 5 minutes, then prompting them to switch to wifi -- I think this would make a for a poor/annoying user experience, as opposed to just prompting them from the start to use wifi. If they use wifi from the start, they will:

1) have less probability of having choppy audio

2) waste less of their cellular data allowance/cost

3) not have a break in service after 5 minutes which might interrupt their flow, at which point they have to fiddle with their phone

Comment: While i agree, there doesn't seem to be an elegant solution here. I have decided to simply give in to Apple's suggestion to disable to feature on 3G :/ Oddly enough, I have streaming video in the app which they don't seem to care about..

Comment: Have you considered down-sampling your audio stream so it uses less bandwidth? Is it an option? Or throttling, as others have mentioned.

Comment: Not an option, there are simply too many streams to have to this with (I'm also not in control of the backend). I had the app approved with the feature taken out but I'm still trying to get it to work via throttling.

Comment: @Keller, Did you ever find a solution for this? I am encountering the same issue,

Answer (score 2):

[ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#throttling_bandwidth) has inbuilt code to throttle bandwidth when the user is on `3G`. This uses a [modified version](http://blog.ddg.com/?p=24) of the Reachability sample. The source is available, so take a peek if you want to try doing this yourself. It dodges the 5mb/5min limit by slowing down the download speed to a rate at which that limit won't be hit.

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest has just been retired by the author, and its design is a bit monolithic. I suggest looking at https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking instead.

Comment: @occulus: +1, but the entire point of this was to read the implementation of bandwidth throttling which uses modified Reachability code. Does `AFNetworking` have a bandwidth throttling option on its requests? If not, then this does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: Two interesting posts! I actually use ASIHTTPRequest in my app for something else (an upload form), so I'll take look at its modified Reachability code. Where did you see it's being retired? Sure it's been a while since last update but it still seems pretty relevant (e.g. works in iOS 5). In any case, I will definitely check out AFNetworking too. Thanks for your responses!

Comment: @Keller: [Here](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D;) is Ben's post announcing the retirement of `ASIHTTPRequest`. He recommends you don't use it for future projects, and start porting existing uses of it to another library like `AFNetworking`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any framework tracks the data usage for you (you get to do that yourself), Reachability is used to find out if you are on WiFi or 3G.